# I have credits from three different graduate programs - can't i combine them into one degree?

Tags: graduate-school

- I started seminary - 6 credits
- Elementary education - 12 credits
- Human Services  - 9 credits

Is there a single "degree" I can combine these into or a university that will accept all the credits to allow it?  Should I consider a multidisciplinary?

Comment: Why aren't you finishing any program? What are you trying to do with your education?

Comment: You've attended 3 grad schools? That's a lot of money spent on application fees and tuition. What is going on that prevents you from finishing any one?

Comment: Welcome to Academia StackExchange! Could you elaborate a bit further? The current skeleton neither helps understand why you changed fields, nor what your ultimate goal might be.

Comment: Also please elaborate what a credit is.
It varies from institution to institution.
Eg my univeristy 48points = 1 year full-time =  8 normal units,
at my friends,  16points = 1 year full-time =  8 normal units,

At my university your total points would repressent not a full year of study

Answer (score 5):

That's entirely up to the institution which you're hoping will grant the degree. Every school has its own policy on what kinds of "transfer credits" it will accept, from what schools, with what grades, for which program and for what portion of the credits needed for that degree. Ask the school. Be prepared to be told that you can avoid only a few classes, and that the CS department considers your A in Fortran For Biology Majors at Wassamatta U to be worth absolutely nothing